# Cannot find test class in project - "The input type of the launch configuration does not exist"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5, testcontainers

I am working with TestContainers for my project but when I am running the test in eclipse, I am having the following error with me
[image: Error window JUnit5]

On top of this window, it also gives a specific error which says **Cannot find test class "DBInitTest" in project "myProject"**.

```java
package org.ft.cdcp;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

@Testcontainers
public class DBInitTest {
    private final PostgreSQLContainer sqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:alpine"));
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        sqlContainer.start();
    }
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Initializing database container")
    public void initTest() {
        assertTrue(sqlContainer.isRunning());
    }
}
```

Do note that I have checked and rechecked the dependencies, everything is intact and there's no problem with them, something's buggy only about JUnit5.

I looked it up online but only found something which said that I should **Right click on source folder --> Build Path --> Use as source path**, but this fix doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the error was.

My project structure was like this:

```
└─main_project/
    ├─ myProject/
    └─ other_sub_project/
```

It might sound stupid but it's definitely something beginners tend to often (as I did). I have opened the main_project in my IDE and there were other sub-projects inside that projects too. The DBInitTest was inside the sub-project named **myProject**.

I was getting the error because of this structure only. So when I closed the project and opened the sub-project directly from the IDE, the error was gone.

Steps to resolve:

1. Close the currently opened project i.e. **main_project**
2. Click on *Open Project* in your IDE
3. Navigate to the folder of the sub-project i.e. **myProject** and open it inside your IDE
4. Voila, the error is gone now. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I am not expert and cannot explain why this fixed any but:-

Today I started having the same problem as you reported.

After fiddling about for a while (reinstalling STS, lombok ...) I eventually clicked on the error entry that popped up. It took me to "Edit lauch configuration properties" for the Test that would not run.

Once there I clicked on the "Search" on the line of the "Test Class:" field.

I selected the correct class from the "Test Selection" window that popped up.
(nb what I thought was the same value that was already there)

### UPDATE

Now I feel silly.

I had a test class called "AdminTaskControllerMockMvcTest" in a file called "AdminTaskControllerMockMvcTests.java", ie class name with an "s" on the end.

Renaming my test class to "AdminTaskControllerMockMvcTests" fixed all my issue.

Regards, Andrew

Comment: Thanx for being silly. Had a similar situation today and fixed it with your advice!

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the class name exactly matches the filename. I have experienced this error and solved after correcting the class name matching with file name

Comment: Yes, I had a hard-to-notice spelling error in my classname and thus the test wasnt found.